# Device support file for iOS 11.4(15g77)

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

I already downloaded the iPhone Device Support [here](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport) . And paste it here on this path

Desktop/xcode8.2/Xcode_8.2.xip Xcode/ Content/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOs.Platform/Device Support

I close my Xcode first before doing the copy and paste stuff then reopen it after doing the copy and paste stuff . But still the error occurs on my Xcode

[image]

I don't know if I'm pasting it on the correct folder of Xcode or not but I'm doing it like that and choosing **SHOW PACKAGE CONTENT**

Comment: Just update your Xcode version

Comment: I don't want to update my Xcode version because I will update my OS also .

Comment: But your current Xcode doesn't support for your phone. You must choice it

Comment: there's no workaround for this?